# Problema con animaciones en Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

soy nuevo en Android y estoy teniendo un problema con transladar objetos de una posición a otra.

Por ejemplo, quiero transladar un `TextView` hacia la posición de otro. Por ende, utilizo la clase `TranslateAnimation(FromX, ToX, FromY, ToY)`. El problema es que no se me mueve a las posiciones que quiero, se va hacia otros lugares. En forma de ejemplo, nombro "tv1" al `TextView` que quiero que se mueva hacia la posición del "tv2".

Entonces hago esto:

```
        TextView tv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);

        float FromX = tv1.getX();
        float FromY = tv1.getY();

        float ToX = tv2.getX();
        float ToY = tv2.getY();

        TranslateAnimation animacion = new TranslateAnimation(FromX, ToX, FromY, ToY);
        animacion.setDuration(1000);
        tv1.startAnimation(animacion);
```

Y no va hacia esa posición, y eso que estoy trabajando en un `FrameLayout` que tiene solamente esos dos componentes. El `tv1` en el centro y el `tv2` en la esquina superior derecha. Si alguien me puede decir que es lo que estoy haciendo mal estaria super agradecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que los metodos `getX()` y `getY()` definen la posicion de la vista en pixeles, pero el constructor que usas define valores tipo `Float` que deben ser valores desde `0.0f` hasta `1.0f`

[TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation#TranslateAnimation(float,%20float,%20float,%20float))

Para el caso de usar pixeles puedes usar este metodo, en el cual el TextView tv1 se movera a la posicion del segundo TextView tv2:

```
   tv1.animate()
            .x(tv2.getX())
            .y(tv2.getY())
            .setDuration(1000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tv1.setX(tv2.getX());
            tv1.setY(tv2.getY());
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Gracias!! Me funcionó perfecto!!